# how to find error the app has stopped react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

how to find error the app has stopped,
guys I'm running my application with react native run android, with this command it works perfectly, but in the final version it shows that the app has stopped.
How to find the error.
I already ran i project in android studio and it shows no error.
It enters the login screen and then shows the error the app has stopped
I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

To trace errors in React-Native use debugger, here is the documentation: 
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging